# Dúvida sobre mapeamento no Entity Framework 6. Propriedades "readonly"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Possuo três tabelas no meu banco:

- TB_COLABORADOR
- TB_JORNADA
- TB_JORNADA_COLABORADOR

A `TB_JORNADA_COLABORADOR` faz a associação dos colaboradores com a jornada e vice-versa através dos campos `COD_JORNADA` e `COD_COLABORADOR`. Ela também possui outros dois campos: `DAT_FIM` e `DAT_INICIO`:

[image: Diagrama]

**A minha dúvida é a seguinte: como mapear de forma que eu possa trazer os dados do colaborador e da jornada em dois campos que adicionei na minha classe (`DadosColaborador` e `DadosJornada`) sem que o Entity Framework tente atualizá-los quando eu for fazer uma persistência de dados:**

```
public partial class JornadaColaborador
{
    public int CodJornadaColaborador { get; set; }
    public int CodJornada { get; set; }
    public int CodColaborador { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> DataFim { get; set; }

    public virtual Colaborador DadosColaborador { get; set; }
    public virtual Jornada DadosJornada { get; set; }
}
```

Meu mapeamento foi feito da seguinte forma (sendo que atualmente estou ignorando a persistência de `DadosColaborador` e `DadosJornada`, só que ao mesmo tempo não consigo trazer os dados deles quando preciso):

```
public class JornadaColaboradorMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<JornadaColaborador>
{
    public JornadaColaboradorMap()
    {
        //Tabela
        ToTable("TB_JORNADA_COLABORADOR");

        //Atributos
        HasKey(t => new { t.CodJornadaColaborador });

        Property(t => t.CodJornadaColaborador).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("COD_JORNADA_COLABORADOR");
        Property(t => t.CodJornada).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed).HasColumnName("COD_JORNADA");
        Property(t => t.CodColaborador).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed).HasColumnName("COD_COLABORADOR");
        Property(t => t.DataInicio).HasColumnName("DAT_INICIO");
        Property(t => t.DataFim).HasColumnName("DAT_FIM");

        Ignore(x => x.DadosColaborador);
        Ignore(x => x.DadosJornada);
    }
}
```

OBS: Estou fazendo a persistência de dados usando métodos genéricos, exemplos:

```
    public void Atualizar(T obj)
    {
        ctx.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        ctx.Entry<T>(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Adicionar(T obj)
    {
        ctx.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        ctx.Set<T>().Add(obj);
    }
```

Comment: Não sei se dá pra fazer isso. Minha sugestão seria carregar a associação dentro de uma *ViewModel* e tratar pontualmente a modificação que você precisa na *Action* que recebe o `POST`. Se quiser coloco isso como resposta.

Comment: Agradeço se puder colocar como resposta para eu compreender melhor.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Foi mal. Na correria deixei pra responder "mais tarde" e acabei não respondendo. Farei isto agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como não existe um mecanismo nativo de garantia de atualização só no primeiro nível de dados, o jeito é fazer um *ViewModel* e realizar as atualizações em manual.

Um operador implícito pode ser uma boa opção aqui:

```
public class JornadaColaboradorViewModel
{
    public int CodJornadaColaborador { get; set; }
    public int CodJornada { get; set; }
    public int CodColaborador { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> DataFim { get; set; }

    public Colaborador DadosColaborador { get; set; }
    public Jornada DadosJornada { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator JornadaColaboradorViewModel(JornadaColaborador jornadaColaborador) 
    {
        return new JornadaColaboradorViewModel 
        {
            CodJornadaColaborador = jornadaColaborador.CodJornadaColaborador,
            CodJornada = jornadaColaborador.CodJornada,
            CodColaborador = jornadaColaborador.CodColaborador,
            DataInicio = jornadaColaborador.DataInicio,
            DataFim = jornadaColaborador.DataFim,
            DadosColaborador = jornadaColaborador.DadosColaborador.
            DadosJornada = jornadaColaborador.DadosJornada
        };
    }
}
```

Observe que eu tirei o *virtual* de propósito. Sem ele, o Entity Framework não identifica que é uma associação, caso alguma atualização ocorra "por acidente".

No *Controller*:

```
var jornadaColaborador = contexto.JornadaColaboradores.SingleOrDefault(/* Coloque algum critério de seleção aqui */);
var jornadaColaboradorViewModel = (JornadaColaboradorViewModel)jornadaColaborador;
return View(jornadaColaboradorViewModel);
```

Não esqueça de mudar a *View*:

```
@model SeuSistema.ViewModels.JornadaColaboradorViewModel
```

Ao salvar, envie normalmente seo *ViewModel* para o *Controller*:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Salvar(JornadaColaboradorViewModel viewModel) 
{
    var jornadaColaboradorOriginal = contexto.JornadaColaboradores.Single(j => j.CodJornadaColaborador = viewModel.CodJornadaColaborador);
    jornadaColaboradorOriginal.CodJornada = viewModel.CodJornada;
    jornadaColaboradorOriginal.CodColaborador = viewModel.CodColaborador;
    jornadaColaboradorOriginal.DataInicio = viewModel.DataInicio;
    jornadaColaboradorOriginal.DataFim = viewModel.DataFim;

    /* Faça o resto da lógica de negócio aqui */
}
```